# iScroll 5, how to detect scroll event

Tags: jquery, iscroll

I want to have my page scroll, and detect if this.y > x pixel, then add a fade in effect for an element on the page. But i can't figure out how to do that while the page is scrolling. I can do it on scrollEnd or scrollStart, but not on scroll.

```
myScroll.on('Scroll',function(){
    console.log(this.y);

    if(this.y < -140){
        $(".permission_content").addClass("fadein");
    }else{

    }

});
```

I am linking to iscroll-probe.js

Please help! Thanks!

Comment: I just added probeType: 2 to my scroll. Now on scroll it detects this.y and i think it is adding the effect correctly. But the scroll is very very jacky. Is this a bug or I am not doing something right?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the documentation for [onscroll](http://iscrolljs.com/#custom-events), `options.probeType` should adjust the rate your function should fire.

Watching scroll events can indeed hurt performance. Although I can't guarantee, you might want to try to `debounce` your handler so it doesn't fire as often. Here's a simple one:

```
function fadeContent () {
    // do animations here
}

var debouncedFade
myScroll.on('scroll', function(){
   clearTimeout(debouncedFade);
   debouncedFade = setTimeout(fadeContent, 100);
});
```